# If $AC = BC$ for every compatible matrix $C$, then does $A = B$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $AC = BC$ for every compatible matrix $C$, then does $A = B$? It seems like it's true, since setting $C$ as a matrix with exactly 1 non-zero entry on its main diagonal, assuming $AC = BC$, then repeating for the rest of the diagonal in $C$ would imply that all of the corresponding columns in A and $B$ are equal. Does this make sense?

Comment: Why don't you just let $C = I$?

Comment: What does compatible mean?

Comment: So the product is well defined I guess @N.S.

Comment: @ClementYung woops didn't think of that, I guess that works too.

Comment: More fundamentally, if $Ax=Bx$ for all vectors $x$, then $A=B$.